# Using forms as filters in laravel, second submit pressed wont send its vaue

Tags: forms, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade

Im using forms to send GET requests in order to use them as filters, however, this is the piece of code I use to do it:

```
{{Form::open(['url'=>action('QuestionController@index'),'method'=>'GET'])}}
    {{Form::hidden('filter',0)}}
    {{Form::submit('TODOS',['class'=>'btn'])}}
{{Form::close()}}

{{Form::open(['url'=>action('QuestionController@index'),'method'=>'GET'])}}
    {{Form::hidden('filter',1)}}
    {{Form::submit('TODOS',['class'=>'btn'])}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

And I handle like this in my controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
    if(\request()->has('filter')){
        $filter=\request('filter');
        if($filter==0){
            $questions=Question::paginate(5);
        }
        if($filter==1){
            $questions=Question::where('revised',0)
                ->paginate(5)
                ->appends('filter',$filter);
        }

    }else{
        $questions=Question::paginate(5);
    }
    return view('layouts.questions.index')->with(compact('questions'));
}
```

The issue is when I click the first button, the filter will work fine and give the url "http://localhost/Maven/public/questions?filter=0", which works as expected. However if now I click the second button, the url will stay the same, and wont change the value of "filter" parameter to "1", as I would expect.

The interesting thing is if I reset the url to "http://localhost/Maven/public/questions" and then click the second filter, it will set the GET variable correctly and give the url "http://localhost/Maven/public/questions?filter=1" with "filter" variable as value "1", which is expected, but if then I click the first submit button (trying to change value of "filter" variable to "0"), the url wont change and stay as filter 1.

I think this may be a basic question, thats why I dont include more code, but I could include full code if requested.

Comment: How is your resulting HTML?

Comment: What you are expecting with this code? Simply  tell us your requirement.

Comment: I expect that when I click the first form submit it will set the "filter" parameter to "0" and when I click the second one the parameter "filter" will be set to "1". This will not happen if I have clicked the first submit and then click the second one afterwards.